# Save multidimensional arrays in WP_Options

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, plugins

Im trying to make a plugin that can save various arrays of data in the same row and looking in youtube making arrays inside of arrays is the only solution I could find

```
$input = get_option( 'wpplugin_settings' );

function wpplugin_sanitize( $input ){

  $output = get_option( 'wpplugin_settings' );

  foreach( $output as $key => $value){
    if ( $input['select_from'] === $key){
      $output[$key] = $input;
    }else{
      $output[$input['select_from']] = $input;
    }
  }
  return $output;


}

wpplugin_sanitize( $input );
```

This is the code that I found in a video, but isn't working for me, it doesn't save my options as an array and just overrides it

-edit

I made a var_dump of the $output

```
array (size=3)
  'select_from' => string 'editor' (length=6)
  'select_to' => string 'contributor' (length=11)
  'editor' => 
    array (size=2)
      'select_from' => string 'editor' (length=6)
      'select_to' => string 'contributor' (length=11)
```

Everything that comes before `'editor' =>` shouldn't be there

Input structure

```
function wpplugin_settings_checkbox_callback( ) {

  $options = get_option( 'wpplugin_settings' );

  $select = '';
    if( isset( $options[ 'select_from' ] ) ) {
        $select = esc_html( $options['select_from'] );
    }

  $html = '<select id="wpplugin_settings_options" name="wpplugin_settings[select_from]">';

  $rolenames = new WP_Roles;
  $rolen = $rolenames->get_names();
  $rolitos = array_keys($rolen);

  foreach ( $rolitos as $rol ){
    $html .= "<option value='$rol'" . selected( $select, $rol , false) . ">" . $rol . "</option>";
  }

    $html .= '</select>';

    echo $html;

}


function wpplugin_settings_select_callback(  ) {

  $options = get_option( 'wpplugin_settings' );

  $select = '';
    if( isset( $options[ 'select_to' ] ) ) {
        $select = esc_html( $options['select_to'] );
    }

  $html = '<select id="wpplugin_settings_options" name="wpplugin_settings[select_to]">';

  $rolenames = new WP_Roles;
  $rolen = $rolenames->get_names();
  $rolitos = array_keys($rolen);

  foreach ( $rolitos as $rol ){
    $html .= "<option value='$rol'" . selected( $select, $rol , false) . ">" . $rol . "</option>";
  }

    $html .= '</select>';

    echo $html;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the problem is actually with saving to WP_Options, or is it just that the data you are saving isn't right? Did you try checking what the array contains?

Comment: Could it be the unwanted array before the 'editor' ?

Comment: Well, if the data you are saving to WP_Options is wrong in the first place, then yes it very well could be! But we don't know what you are trying to save so we can't really help you fix. You'll need to give us some more info about the structure of your input is and how it should be restructured, so we can see what might be going wrong.

Comment: There only two select inputs that display the roles of a a site

Comment: if you want to save an array in your db you can make a string out of it by using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) - just remember to [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it again upon reading.